# Unable to store model in Id column. The type was expected to be Int32

Tags: c#, datatable

**I get the error:**
*"System.ArgumentException:" Could not cast object type "WinForm.Model.EntityModel" to type "System.IConvertible". Unable to save <WinForm.Model.EntityModel> in Id column. Type Int32 expected "*

**Question.**
How do I resolve the error?

Code **EntityModel.cs**

```
namespace WinForm.Model
{
    class EntityModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string String_Prop { get; set; }
        public int Int_Prop { get; set; }      
        
    }
}
```

Code **Form1.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WinForm.Model;
using System.Data;
 
namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("String", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Int", typeof(int));
            
            dt.Rows.Add(new EntityModel { Id = 1, String_Prop = "String_1", Int_Prop = 11 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new EntityModel { Id = 2, String_Prop = "String_2", Int_Prop = 12 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new EntityModel { Id = 3, String_Prop = "String_3", Int_Prop = 13 });
        }
    }
}
```

**Picture-1**
[image]

Comment: You are trying to add an `EntityModel` object as a row in a `DataTable`. `Rows.Add` expects a `DataRow` object or something convertible to one

Comment: @Flydog57 Is it better to do this? `dt.Rows.Add (1," String_1 ", 11);`

Comment: Does that code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with the intermediate List:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WinForm.Model;
using System.Data;
 
namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("String", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Int", typeof(int));
            
            dt.Rows.Add(MkRow(1, "String_1", 11));
            dt.Rows.Add(MkRow(2, "String_2", 12));
            dt.Rows.Add(MkRow(3, "String_3", 13));
        }

        private static DataRow MkRow(DataTable dt, int id, string String_Prop, int Int_Prop)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = id;
            row["String_Prop"] = String_Prop;
            row["Int_Prop"] = Int_Prop;
            return row;
        }
        
    }
}
```

The key, as Flydog57 said, is to ensure you have a [DataRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with your `EntityModel` class (for example, it's a real model that you are using somewhere else in your program), you could provide a way to create a `DataRow` from an instance of an `EntityModel`

For example, you could do something like this:

```
public DataRow ToDataRow(DataTable dt)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = Id;
    row["String"] = String_Prop;
    row["Int"] = Int_Prop;
    return row;
}
```

or, if you are very sure of the order of things in your row, you could skip the column name lookup and do something like:

```
public DataRow ToDataRow(DataTable dt)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = Id;
    row[1] = String_Prop;
    row[2] = Int_Prop;
    return row;
}
```

Then you can call `.ToDataRow(dt)` on each `EntityModel` instance.

I was hoping that there might be a very clear way to use a C# *deconstructor* method to get this done.  It's not as straightforward as I thought, but this should work:

First add a Deconstructor to `EntityModel`

```
public void Deconstruct(out int id, out string stringProp, out int intProp)
{
    id = Id;
    stringProp = String_Prop;
    intProp = Int_Prop;
}
```

Then, if you are working with a collection of entities, say, something like this:

```
var entities = new List<EntityModel>
{
    new EntityModel {Id = 1, String_Prop = "String_1", Int_Prop = 11},
    new EntityModel {Id = 2, String_Prop = "String_2", Int_Prop = 12},
    new EntityModel {Id = 3, String_Prop = "String_3", Int_Prop = 13},
};
```

you can write code that looks like this:

```
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    (int id, string stringProp, int intProp) = entity;
    dt.Rows.Add(id, stringProp, intProp);
}
```

That's pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

To add rows to a DataTable, you must first use the [`NewRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=netcore-3.1) method to return a new [`DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netcore-3.1) object.

In your case, the sample code -

```
  List<EntityModel> list = new List<EntityModel>();

  list.Add(new EntityModel { Id = 1, String_Prop = "String_1", Int_Prop = 11 });
  list.Add(new EntityModel { Id = 2, String_Prop = "String_2", Int_Prop = 12 });
  list.Add(new EntityModel { Id = 3, String_Prop = "String_3", Int_Prop = 13 });

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
   dt.Columns.Add("String", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("Int", typeof(int));
        
   foreach (var item in list)
     {
      var row = dt.NewRow();

      row["Id"] = item.Id;
      row["String"] = item.String_Prop;
      row["Int"] = item.Int_Prop;
      dt.Rows.Add(row);
     }
```